# Ajax Chat long polling

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf

After reading [this post](http://anthymecaillard.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/wcf-real-time-web-development-with-long-polling/), I decided to write my own chat application.

Differently from the above post, my application allows more polling, for instance when user presses any key (in order to inform the other one that user1 is writing something) and obviously when a user sends a message.

This causes some problems: often no-one notification is read correctly and the sent message isn't always read from the other side.

It could be great if there was some way to send and receive different notificaion types (message, alert about new writing, new user joined and so on...).

How can I solve this?

Comment: Look into Comet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: Look into the "the amazing SignalR"  http://signalr.net/

Comment: I 'd like to implment my custom library without using third party solutions..

Comment: Implementing all this would be quite a lot of work and definitely not something that could fit in a single StackOverflow answer. So use SignalR. If you don't want to use it and reinvent wheels then start reinventing them but come back to ask here only very specific questions about your implementation and don't just ask how to write a chat application as this means nothing.

Comment: XMPP is a protocol written to do exactly what you are attempting to do. I'd recommend considering building on top of it using a library like [Strophe](http://strophe.im/). As Darin said, if you really want to build this from scratch, then the scope of your question is way too large for a single StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad to inform you my chat app are working now.

The problem was about two call to wcf service in the same javascript eventhandler (send message button, where I notiified the new message and an alert such as "user is not writing anything", yeah, I needed to reset the previous alert ("user is writing a message..").

Now I'm be able to send and receive many notification and all works fine. I've tested it with 10 chat page about.

Surely I know I can achieve more functionality and stability by using the framework you have suggested me, but I'm happy to have found a relative simple, customizable and good solution for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Signal R is the solution to your problem. I understand that you want to develop your own solution and that the intrigue can be enticing BUT please consider looking into SignalR - being able to get to grips with and manipulate SignalR will pay dividends and allow you to solve similar problems much more easily - its a great tool to add to your development arsenal.

In fact by all means continue developing your solution but give SignalR the once over for something else or another project it really is worth looking at as the de facto method of achieving this type of client server communication within .net. It can be found on NuGet using the link below so its only a few clicks away!

http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR